# pagebreak on coldfusion cfcontent word document

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word, document, coldfusion-8

I am using cfcontent for creating a Word Document.

Example :

```
<cfsavecontent variable="sStr">
   part1
   part2
   part3 
</cfsavecontent>

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=wordDoc.doc">
<cfcontent type="application/msword" variable="#sStr#">
```

I want page break after each part.

The output should be in landscape format. How can I do this?

Comment: Technically that does not create an MS Word Document, but HTML which Word can *interpret*. What have you tried so far? What I usually suggest is creating a "real" Word document with the features you want. Keep it very simple. Then save it as HTML and see how MS Word does it and research the details in the [MS HTML and XML reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

For a page break you should be using:

```
<cfdocumentitem type="pagebreak" />
```

And landscape you can set by:

```
<cfdocument orientation = "portrait|landscape>
```

As far as I know it's not possible to change the orientation of an individual page.

Comment: thanks rick for your reply, i edited my question please help with that.

Comment: Yes, that works for creating pdf's. However, the OP is actually creating a faux-MS Word document using HTML. That is not supported by cfdocument.

Answer (score 1):

For cfcontent of a file you've saved to create an MS Word document:

```
<br clear=3Dall style=3D'page-break-before:always;mso-break-type:section-break'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got Page orientation to work with ms word by using the following style and making sure in cfcontent reset="no";

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<title>Work Order Report</title>
<style>
 @page Section1
 {   size:11.0in 8.5in;
     mso-page-orientation:landscape;
 }

 body.section1 {page:section1;}
</style>
<body class="section1">
<cfcontent type="application/msword" reset="no">
```